# GUI package to use on jupyter notebook (Selecting Points on an image)

Tags: python, graphics, computer-vision

The context of my Computer Vision assignment: Computing a homography matrix, where one of the tasks is to create a GUI to select points on the images (to get the coordinates, and pixel values).

I've looked through StackOverflow and found some options, i.e using tkinter, but the answers were from 2011. I was wondering whether there are other or new options out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that worked for me using openCV 3.3.1 
For camera calibration see my github repo https://github.com/abhishek098/camera_calibration .

```
import numpy as np
import yaml
import cv2


'''
1. change the path to load image and store data 
2. double click on the image to save the co-ordinates   
3. images should be named as 0.jpg, 1.jpg, 2.jpg .....
4. 
'''

# set image and data path here..
path = "/home/abhishek/stuff/object_detection/explore/"



points = []

def mouseCB(event,x,y,flags,param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK :
        print (x, y)
        points.append([x, y])


count = 0

exit_flag = True

points_list = []

while exit_flag:
    window_name = 'image_' + str(count)
    cv2.namedWindow(window_name)
    cv2.setMouseCallback(window_name, mouseCB)
    image_name = path + str(count) + '.jpg'
    img = cv2.imread(image_name)
    cv2.imshow(window_name, img)

    while True:

        ip = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
        if ip == ord('n'):
            count += 1
            points_list.append(points)
            points = []
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
        elif ip == ord('q'):
            exit_flag = False
            break
    print (count)

data = {'img_co': np.asarray(points_list).tolist()}
file = path + "data.yaml"
with open(file, "w") as f:
    yaml.dump(data, f)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```